# WKWebview is not rendering .docx file accurately, docx contains logos in header and watermarks, which are not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, docx

`WKWebView` is not rendering .docx file accurately. The docx file has logos in header and watermark at the background which is not displayed correctly to the user.

Getting the document data from a server using JSON encoded to Base64.

Steps taken to load the docx file in WKWebview:

1. Stored the document data on app documents directory.
2. Displaying the document file in `WKWebView` on mobile app with help of local document directory file path.

Below is the code that renders the docx file:

```swift
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let filePath = String(format: "%@/%@", documentsPath, "file.docx")
                
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
docWebView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Ask your's server to provide PDF or better HTML